# What policies/laws required Michael Flynn to get permission for funds from Russia and Turkey?

Tags: united-states

In *[Michael Flynn's Russia payment likely broke disclosure laws, lawmakers say](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/apr/25/michael-flynn-russia-payment-house-panel-investigation)*:

> In 2015, Flynn received about $45,000 for attending Russian state TV
> network RT’s gala dinner in Moscow, where he sat next to Russian
> president Vladimir Putin. He also received $530,000 for consulting
> work that likely benefited the Turkish government while working as a
> top adviser to Trump’s presidential campaign.
>
> [ **...** ]
>
> “He was supposed to get permission, he was supposed to report it, and
> he didn’t,” Cummings said.

What is Elijah Cummings referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Cummings is referring to

1. US military regulations designed to bring about compliance with the Emoluments Clause of the US constitution, which forbids US officials such as military reservists from receiving payments from foreign governments. Any suspect payments must be cleared in advance.
2. Disclosure requirements when seeking security clearance.

Comment: Interesting, could you add some sources (for future readers and myself whom are an outsider to US politics generally) to verify this?

Comment: I don't know the exact specifics of this case, but if the payments were from a foreign government, [37 USC 908](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/37/908) is at least one of the relevant laws (for point 1).

Comment: Actually, emoluments is specifically about payments **for services related to one's position in US government**. If Flynn was paid for teaching someone to drive (using exaggregated exampe) that has nothing to do with Emoluments whatsoever (though questionable whether still falls under military regulations that may of course be broader). "consulting" is rather... vague to know if it was or wasn't related to his government position.

Comment: I down-voted this due to the lack of verification with references, I'm more than happy to retract that if you provide sources that can verify what you have written.

Comment: @user4012 but if he teaches someone to drive a tank, that might be against the law.   ;-)